# What is the proper way to use SolrCloud from out of k8s cluster?

Tags: solrj, solrcloud, solr4j

I'm trying to use solr, which is working on Kubernetes, from out of k8s. Even I use "HttpSolrClient" java client it tries to connect internal k8s solr instance.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Tried fetching cluster state using the node names we knew of, i.e. [solr-1.solrcluster:8983_solr, solr-2.solrcluster:8983_solr, solr-0.solrcluster:8983_solr]. However, succeeded in obtaining the cluster state from none of them.If you think your Solr cluster is up and is accessible, you could try re-creating a new CloudSolrClient using working solrUrl(s) or zkHost(s)

Just balancer Ip accessible for the client not all SolrCloud nodes.
What is the proper way to use solr client from out of k8s ?